# How to show old style permission request screen?

Tags: facebook, permissions, dialog, facebook-authentication

In almost every game i try in facebook i see all permissions in one initial screen, and "Allow" & "Not Allow" buttons.  I want to display such dialog window, but turning off "Enhanced Auth Dialog" in Advanced settings doesn't help. :(  My dialog always came with "Go to APP" button.  Problem is, my client wants this dialog to be displayed in the middle of the app. First steps in the app are anonymous and not require authorisation, it needed actually at the very end, when info is collected. "Go to app" button in this case doesn't make any sense. How to show dialog with "Allow" button?
I tried calling it by several methods, but every time it's new oAuth.
Please, help.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me: The authorization dialog only displays when **you**, the programmer decide to show it. If you have an anonymous portion of your app, don't do any authorization.

Comment: This is not this question is about. I have seen many apps with old style dialog - how they do it? In this case i am doing contract work, so if client wants it this way, i should find a way, if any.

Comment: So the problem for me is the disabling Enhanced Dialog does nothing for some reason. It's definitly disabled in Advanced settings, but when i display Auth dialog, by any method, it's always new one. But other apps do it somehow, so there is a way. Why it does't work in my app?

Comment: If you use an old app it's possible to make use of some old methods, but those methods are not available for the new apps you may build.

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations for some or all users, Facebook will force you to use the new dialog. Eventually all apps will be forced to migrate to the new dialog so just accept it and move on.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/enhanced-auth-dialog-and-updates-to-permissions

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap